# 24 format for data from a select query

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, visual-studio-2008, time

I am running a query in C++ but I can not get the date to process correctly. I want to date to return in 24 hr date time format (dd/mm/yyyy Hh24:mi:ss). I have run the query in MS Access as follows:

```
SELECT Format(Data.[Date / Time],'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss'), DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Total], DATA.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Total], DATA.[Electro-Arc Furnace Total], DATA.[J-9 Shop Total], DATA.[Levy Maintence Building Total], DATA.[Ford Body Shop Total], DATA.[Ford Chiller Building Total], DATA.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Total], DATA.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Total], DATA.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Total], DATA.[Ford Final Assembly Total], DATA.[Ford Frame Plant Total], DATA.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Total], DATA.[Ford Tool and Die Total], DATA.[Ford Paint Plant Total], DATA.[Ford Glass Plant Total], DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Rate], DATA.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate], DATA.[Electro-Arc Furnace Rate], DATA.[J-9 Shop Rate], DATA.[Levy Maintence Building Rate], DATA.[Ford Body Shop Rate], DATA.[Ford Chiller Building Rate], DATA.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate], DATA.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate], DATA.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate], DATA.[Ford Final Assembly Rate], DATA.[Ford Frame Plant Rate], DATA.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate], DATA.[Ford Tool and Die Rate], DATA.[Ford Paint Plant Rate], DATA.[Ford Glass Plant Rate]
FROM DATA;
```

Which runs fine; however when I run this in my code I get the following error:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Date/ Time
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookUp.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)

at system.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetOrdinal(String value)

at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.get_Item(String value)

...at line 120 of my code

Code someone help me to make sense of this. This is the very last component of my code that I have to handle right now and I would really love to just be done with it thank you for all of your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString = "Dsn=Gas_meter_check";

        string dayTime = "";
        string hsmt = "";
        string boft = "";
        string eaft = "";
        string j9st = "";
        string lmbt = "";
        string fbst = "";
        string fcbt = "";
        string fdwpt ="";

        string fdept = "";
        string fdbt = "";
        string ffat = "";
        string ffpt = "";
        string fdnpt = "";
        string ftdt = "";
        string fppt = "";
        string fgpt = "";

        string hsmr = "";
        string bofr = "";
        string eafr = "";
        string j9sr = "";
        string lmbr = "";
        string fbsr = "";
        string fcbr = "";
        string fdwpr = "";

        string fdepr = "";
        string fdbr = "";
        string ffar = "";
        string ffpr = "";
        string fdnpr = "";
        string ftdr = "";
        string fppr = "";
        string fgpr = "";

        string sqlins = "";
        string connString = "DSN=Gas_Reporter_proj;Uid=rouge;Pwd=steel";
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connString);

        OdbcConnection DbConnection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
        OdbcCommand DbCommand = DbConnection.CreateCommand();
        DbConnection.Open();
        //DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Data.[Date / Time],Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Total],Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Total],Data.[J-9 Shop Total],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Total],Data.[Ford Body Shop Total], Data.[Ford Chiller Building Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Total], Data.[Ford Final Assembly Total],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Total],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Total], Data.[Ford Paint Plant Total],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Total], Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate], Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Rate],Data.[J-9 Shop Rate],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Rate],Data.[Ford Body Shop Rate],Data.[Ford Chiller Building Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate],Data.[Ford Final Assembly Rate],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Rate],Data.[Ford Paint Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Rate]FROM DATA";
        //THIS IS FOR WHEN THE THE INITIAL DATA IS UPLOADED
        //DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Data.[Date / Time],Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Total],Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Total],Data.[J-9 Shop Total],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Total],Data.[Ford Body Shop Total], Data.[Ford Chiller Building Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Total], Data.[Ford Final Assembly Total],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Total],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Total], Data.[Ford Paint Plant Total],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Total], Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate], Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Rate],Data.[J-9 Shop Rate],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Rate],Data.[Ford Body Shop Rate],Data.[Ford Chiller Building Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate],Data.[Ford Final Assembly Rate],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Rate],Data.[Ford Paint Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Rate]FROM DATA WHERE Format( Data.[Date / Time], 'mm/dd/yyyy') >=(select Format(max( Data.[Date / Time]),'mm/dd/yyyy') from DATA)";
        // THIS IS FOR WHEN THE HOT MILL WORKING;
        DbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Format(Data.[Date / Time],'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss'),DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Total],Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Total],Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Total],Data.[J-9 Shop Total],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Total],Data.[Ford Body Shop Total], Data.[Ford Chiller Building Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Total],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Total], Data.[Ford Final Assembly Total],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Total], Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Total],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Total], Data.[Ford Paint Plant Total],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Total], DATA.[Hot Strip Mill Rate], Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate], Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Rate],Data.[J-9 Shop Rate],Data.[Levy Maintence Building Rate],Data.[Ford Body Shop Rate],Data.[Ford Chiller Building Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate],Data.[Ford Final Assembly Rate],Data.[Ford Frame Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Tool and Die Rate],Data.[Ford Paint Plant Rate],Data.[Ford Glass Plant Rate]FROM DATA";
        //WHERE Format( Data.[Date / Time], 'mm/dd/yyyy') >=(select Format(max( Data.[Date / Time]),'mm/dd/yyyy') from DATA)
        OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int fCount = DbReader.FieldCount;
 try
{
        OdbcCommand cmdnon = new OdbcCommand(sqlins, conn);                            
        conn.Open();

        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(dayTime, OdbcType.DateTime);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(hsmt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(boft, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(eaft, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(j9st, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(lmbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fbst, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fcbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdwpt, OdbcType.Numeric);

        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdept, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdbt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffat, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdnpt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ftdt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fppt, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fgpt, OdbcType.Numeric);

        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(hsmr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(bofr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(eafr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(j9sr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(lmbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fbsr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fcbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdwpr, OdbcType.Numeric);

        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdepr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdbr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffar, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ffpr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fdnpr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(ftdr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fppr, OdbcType.Numeric);
        cmdnon.Parameters.Add(fgpr, OdbcType.Numeric);




        while (DbReader.Read())
                    {
                        dayTime = DbReader["Date / Time"].ToString();
                        hsmt = DbReader["Hot Strip Mill Total"].ToString();     
                        boft = DbReader["Basic Oxygen Furnace Total"].ToString();   
                        eaft = DbReader["Electro-Arc Furnace Total"].ToString(); 
                        j9st = DbReader["J-9 Shop Total"].ToString();
                        lmbt = DbReader["Levy Maintence Building Total"].ToString();
                        fbst = DbReader["Ford Body Shop Total"].ToString();    
                        fcbt = DbReader["Ford Chiller Building Total"].ToString(); 
                        fdwpt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn W Plant Total"].ToString();  


                        fdept = DbReader["Ford Dearborn E Plant Total"].ToString();
                        fdbt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn Balcony Total"].ToString();    
                        ffat = DbReader["Ford Final Assembly Total"].ToString();  
                        ffpt = DbReader["Ford Frame Plant Total"].ToString();  
                        fdnpt = DbReader["Ford Dearborn N Plant Total"].ToString();
                        ftdt = DbReader["Ford Tool and Die Total"].ToString();    
                        fppt = DbReader["Ford Paint Plant Total"].ToString();    
                        fgpt = DbReader["Ford Glass Plant Total"].ToString();  

                        hsmr = DbReader["Hot Strip Mill Rate"].ToString();
                        bofr = DbReader["Basic Oxygen Furnace Rate"].ToString();   
                        eafr = DbReader["Electro-Arc Furnace Rate"].ToString(); 
                        j9sr = DbReader["J-9 Shop Rate"].ToString();          
                        lmbr = DbReader["Levy Maintence Building Rate"].ToString();                            
                        fbsr = DbReader["Ford Body Shop Rate"].ToString();   
                        fcbr = DbReader["Ford Chiller Building Rate"].ToString();
                        fdwpr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn W Plant Rate"].ToString();

                        fdepr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn E Plant Rate"].ToString();
                        fdbr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn Balcony Rate"].ToString();   
                        ffar = DbReader["Ford Final Assembly Rate"].ToString();   
                        ffpr = DbReader["Ford Frame Plant Rate"].ToString();     
                        fdnpr = DbReader["Ford Dearborn N Plant Rate"].ToString(); 
                        ftdr = DbReader["Ford Tool and Die Rate"].ToString();     
                        fppr = DbReader["Ford Paint Plant Rate"].ToString();    
                        fgpr = DbReader["Ford Glass Plant Rate"].ToString();

                        //cmdnon.CommandText = "insert into NAT_GAS_READINGS(BOF_TOTAL,EAF_TOTAL,J9_SHOP_TOTAL,LEVY_TOTAL,BODY_SHOP_TOTAL,CHILLER_BLDG_TOTAL,WPLANT_TOTAL,EPLANT_TOTAL,BALCONY_TOTAL,FINAL_ASSEMBLY_TOTAL,FRAME_PLANT_TOTAL,NPLANT_TOTAL,TOOL_DIE_TOTAL,PAINT_PLANT_TOTAL,GLASS_PLANT_TOTAL,BOF,EAF,J9_SHOP,LEVY,BODY_SHOP,CHILLER_BLDG,WPLANT,EPLANT,BALCONY,FINAL_ASSEMBLY,FRAME_PLANT,NPLANT,TOOL_DIE,PAINT_PLANT,GLASS_PLANT,DATETIME) values ( to_number(1564),to_number(1385), to_number(87886),to_number(687489.25),to_number(9879.35),to_number(897.54),to_number(98754.38),to_number(768.47), to_number(654), to_number(897896),to_number(8978.18),to_number(897234), to_number(3546.28),to_number(54798),to_number(65496), to_number(6487), to_number(98796), to_number(6485), to_number(5488), to_number(65496),to_number(65465),to_number(1411), to_number(3354), to_number(54879),to_number(35),to_number(21),to_number(325),to_number(3215),to_number(3215),to_number(214))";
                        //cmdnon.CommandText = "insert into NAT_GAS_READINGS(BOF_TOTAL,EAF_TOTAL,J9_SHOP_TOTAL,LEVY_TOTAL,BODY_SHOP_TOTAL,CHILLER_BLDG_TOTAL,WPLANT_TOTAL,EPLANT_TOTAL,BALCONY_TOTAL,FINAL_ASSEMBLY_TOTAL,FRAME_PLANT_TOTAL,NPLANT_TOTAL,TOOL_DIE_TOTAL,PAINT_PLANT_TOTAL,GLASS_PLANT_TOTAL,BOF,EAF,J9_SHOP,LEVY,BODY_SHOP,CHILLER_BLDG,WPLANT,EPLANT,BALCONY,FINAL_ASSEMBLY,FRAME_PLANT,NPLANT,TOOL_DIE,PAINT_PLANT,GLASS_PLANT,DATETIME) values (to_number('" + boft + "'), to_number('" + eaft + "'), to_number('" + j9st + "'), to_number('" + lmbt + "'),to_number('" + fbst + "'),to_number('" + fcbt + "'),to_number('" + fdwpt + "'), to_number('" + fdept + "'), to_number('" + fdbt + "'), to_number('" + ffat + "'), to_number('" + ffpt + "'), to_number('" + fdnpt + "'), to_number('" + ftdt + "'), to_number('" + fppt + "'), to_number('" + fgpt + "'), to_number('" + bofr + "'), to_number('" + eafr + "'), to_number('" + j9sr + "'), to_number('" + lmbr + "'), to_number('" + fbsr + "'), to_number('" + fcbr + "'), to_number('" + fdwpr + "'), to_number('" + fdepr + "'),  to_number('" + fdbr + "'), to_number('" + ffar + "'), to_number('" + ffpr + "'), to_number('" + fdnpr + "'), to_number('" + ftdr + "'), to_number('" + fppr + "'),to_number('" + fgpr + "'),to_date('" + dayTime + "', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' ))";
                        //cmdnon.CommandText = "insert into NAT_GAS_READINGS( HSM_TOTAL,BOF_TOTAL,EAF_T0TAL,J9_SHOP_TOTAL,LEVY_TOTAL,BODY_SHOP_TOTAL,CHILLER_BLDG_TOTAL,WPLANT_TOTAL,EPLANT_TOTAL,BALCONY_TOTAL,FINAL_ASSEMBLY_TOTAL,FRAME_PLANT_TOTAL,NPLANT_TOTAL,TOOL_DIE_TOTAL,PAINT_PLANT_TOTAL,GLASS_PLANT_TOTAL,HSM,BOF,EAF,J9_SHOP,LEVY,BODY_SHOP,CHILLER_BLDG,WPLANT,EPLANT,BALCONY,FINAL_ASSEMBLY,FRAME_PLANT,NPLANT,TOOL_DIE,PAINT_PLANT,GLASS_PLANT,DATETIME) values (to_number('" + hsmt + "'), to_number('" + boft + "'), to_number('" + eaft + "'), to_number('" + j9st + "'), to_number('" + lmbt + "'),to_number('" + fbst + "'),to_number('" + fcbt + "'), to_number('" + fdwpt + "'), to_number('" + fdept + "'), to_number('" + fdbt + "'), to_number('" + ffat + "'), to_number('" + ffpt + "'), to_number('" + fdnpt + "'), to_number('" + ftdt + "'), to_number('" + fppt + "'), to_number('" + fgpt + "'), to_number('" + hsmr + "'), to_number('" + bofr + "'), to_number('" + eafr + "'), to_number('" + j9sr + "'), to_number('" + lmbr + "'), to_number('" + fbsr + "'), to_number('" + fcbr + "'), to_number('" + fdwpr + "'), to_number('" + fdepr + "'), to_number('" + fdbr + "'), to_number('" + ffar + "'), to_number('" + ffpr + "'), to_number('" + fdnpr + "'), to_number('" + ftdr + "'), to_number('" + fppr + "'), to_number('" + fgpr + "'), to_date('" + dayTime + "', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ))";
                        cmdnon.CommandText = "insert into NAT_GAS_READINGS( HSM_TOTAL,BOF_TOTAL,EAF_TOTAL,J9_SHOP_TOTAL,LEVY_TOTAL,BODY_SHOP_TOTAL,CHILLER_BLDG_TOTAL,WPLANT_TOTAL,EPLANT_TOTAL,BALCONY_TOTAL,FINAL_ASSEMBLY_TOTAL,FRAME_PLANT_TOTAL,NPLANT_TOTAL,TOOL_DIE_TOTAL,PAINT_PLANT_TOTAL,GLASS_PLANT_TOTAL,HSM,BOF,EAF,J9_SHOP,LEVY,BODY_SHOP,CHILLER_BLDG,WPLANT,EPLANT,BALCONY,FINAL_ASSEMBLY,FRAME_PLANT,NPLANT,TOOL_DIE,PAINT_PLANT,GLASS_PLANT,DATETIME) values (to_number('" + hsmt + "'), to_number('" + boft + "'), to_number('" + eaft + "'), to_number('" + j9st + "'), to_number('" + lmbt + "'),to_number('" + fbst + "'),to_number('" + fcbt + "'), to_number('" + fdwpt + "'), to_number('" + fdept + "'), to_number('" + fdbt + "'), to_number('" + ffat + "'), to_number('" + ffpt + "'), to_number('" + fdnpt + "'), to_number('" + ftdt + "'), to_number('" + fppt + "'), to_number('" + fgpt + "'), to_number('" + hsmr + "'), to_number('" + bofr + "'), to_number('" + eafr + "'), to_number('" + j9sr + "'), to_number('" + lmbr + "'), to_number('" + fbsr + "'), to_number('" + fcbr + "'), to_number('" + fdwpr + "'), to_number('" + fdepr + "'), to_number('" + fdbr + "'), to_number('" + ffar + "'), to_number('" + ffpr + "'), to_number('" + fdnpr + "'), to_number('" + ftdr + "'), to_number('" + fppr + "'), to_number('" + fgpr + "'), to_date('01/24/1987 23:54:12', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ))";
                        int rowsAffected = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected);

                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();                       
                }
   DbReader.Close();
   DbCommand.Dispose();
   DbConnection.Close();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to add that I didn't create the Access table so I am not responsible for the terrible format of the column names.

Comment: Right tag? The code looks more like C#.

Comment: Date format is a presentation-layer issue, and you shouldn't be worrying about it in your SQL.

Comment: @ Rene, sorry about that I forgot to fix that, the last question that I asked was in C++ so it just carried over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/90a7b8k5.aspx :

Description of OdbcDataReader::Item

```
IndexOutOfRangeException : No column with the specified name was found.
```

Obviously there is a problem in naming the database table columns.

Tip: Try to get the fields by field number first. Then try `OdbcDataReader::GetName(number)` to get the column name.

*Edit:*

```
dayTime = DbReader.GetString(0); // or
dayTime = DbReader.GetString("Date / Time");
```

seems more readable to me.

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with the name bc I added the following line: 
Console.WriteLine(DbReader["Date / time"].ToString());

 afterdaytime = DbReader["Date / time"].ToString());

Comment: @Dante: Yes, but then you shouldn't get an IndexOutOfRangeException from the square brackets in `DbReader[...]`, which indicates, that there is no mapping from the column name string to a zero-based column number. Now you use `"Date / time"` instead of `"Date / Time"`? Maybe SQL is not case-sensitive, but C# is.

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with the name bc I added the following line: 
Console.WriteLine(DbReader["Date / time"].ToString()); 
after
daytime = DbReader["Date / time"].ToString());
then when I run the program with a break after that line, I recieved the data in its given format. I still need the data in 
this format:"7/1/2011 16:01:07" instead of "07/1/2011 4:01:07 PM"

Comment: I have run the code with and without "Format(Data.[Date / Time],'mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss')" instead using Data.[Date / Time], the console window shows me the date (7/1/2011 4:01:07 PM ) but the error new error is ora-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string tips